# How to include nested model in Sequelize hook?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a piece of code which looks like

```
 Feed.hook('afterCreate', function(doc, fields, fn) {
    onSave(socket, doc);
    fn(null);
  });
```

`Feed` has a many-to-one relationship with `Printer`, meaning that a `Feed` belongs to a `Printer`.

What I want is something similar to:

```
Feed.findAll({include: [Owner, Language]})
    .then(responseWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
```

but for this specific case.

How can I include the `Printer` object corresponding to this `Feed`?

Comment: you just wrote it
    Feed.findAll({include: [Printer]})

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it properly, but I want it included in that `.hook()` statement somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using the usual approach for hooks and later on using `sequelize`'s `models` to access any model you need, a `Promise` could be needed as well.

Not sure why do you need to find something including other objects on the `afterCreate` hook, but that should work as this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Feed', {
    description: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    hooks: {
      afterCreate: [
        function (obj) {
          return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            sequelize.models.Feed.findAll({include: [sequelize.models.Owner, sequelize.models.Language]})
             .then(resolve)
             .catch(reject);
          };
        }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

This way you wouldn't need another require for your models inside a model definition. But using your currently approach, you would need a `sequelize` instance to access them.